# Show one div on click of the other without using *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

When I click on 1st `<div>` it should hide, when I click on 2nd `<div>` the second `<div>` should hide but 1st should appear. Similarly when I click on any `<div>` it should hide but other hidden `<div>` should appear. What I achieved is, onclick on `<div>` it is hidding but onclick of another `<div>` the hidden `<div>` is not appearing back. Please suggest what to do.

NOTE: I have to iterate over and hide the same  and I cannot use *ngIf and *ngFor on same

```
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index" (click)="episode.showDiv = false" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black">
  tile{{i}}  
</div>


import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  hide = null;
  episodes = [
    { title: 'Winter Is Coming', director: 'Tim Van Patten', 'showDiv': true },
    { title: 'The Kingsroad', director: 'Tim Van Patten', 'showDiv': true },
    { title: 'Lord Snow', director: 'Brian Kirk', 'showDiv': true },
    { title: 'Cripples, Bastards, and Broken Things', director: 'Brian Kirk', 'showDiv': true },
    { title: 'The Wolf and the Lion', director: 'Brian Kirk', 'showDiv': true },
    { title: 'A Golden Crown', director: 'Daniel Minahan', 'showDiv': true },
    { title: 'You Win or You Die', director: 'Daniel Minahan', 'showDiv': true },
    { title: 'The Pointy End', director: 'Daniel Minahan', 'showDiv': true }
  ];


}
```

Comment: You are not setting the `showDiv` back to true when clicking on another div. Bind a function to your click which turns all `showDiv` to true and only the one clicked to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No to pretty, but something like this in your component

```
onClick(event: any) {
     for(let i = 0; i < this.episodes.length; i++) {
         if(this.episodes[i] == event) {
              this.episodes[i].showDiv = false;
         } else {
              this.episodes[i].showDiv = true;
         }
     }
}
```

And in your html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let episode of episodes; let i = index">
    <div class="tiles" *ngIf="episode.showDiv" (click)="onClick(episode)" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid black">
        tile{{i}}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjmjdq) is a working stackblitz btw.

Comment: can i do it without using *ngIf, i have to iterate over and hide the same <div> and I cannot use *ngIf and *ngFor on same <div>

Comment: While you can apply `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` to the same element, that won't  work in your case, because if the `*ngIf` is false the element is not displayed and therfor the `*ngFor` will not be in your dom aswell. If you dont want to have a `<div>` for `*ngFor` than you could use the `<ng-container>` element which is not rendered to the dom.

Comment: @Anna would be great if you accept the awnser if it was helpful